# Marker in Google Maps

Tags: api, google-maps

My map(V3) is loaded into an iframe. I need to find the pixel co ordinates of each marker relative to the iframe. Could someone tell me how to do that please? Thanks a ton.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check the API how to add overlays [Google Maps V3 API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html)

Comment: I tried using the method suggested in the tutorial ,i.e., fromLatLngToDivPixel(). But it doesn't work:(:(

Comment: Is there any method at all to achieve this? Please could someone come up with a solution? Thanks.